# zip a folder with all its content without preserving directory structure in Python

Tags: python, zip, shutil

I have directory and has many csv files in it. When i try to zip the folder using zipfile or shutil package, then a complete directory structure is getting created. I just need to get the folder with lot of csv files zipped.

Comment: Perhaps you would like to post a [mre] showing what you are currently doing.

Comment: if i understand correctly you want a zip that only contains the csv files but not the directory right?

Comment: I have project structure like data/Final Data/ csv files. How i need solution when zip is performed is data.zip which when unzipped should give us Final Data/csv files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import shutil
import os


def make_archive(source, destination):
    base = os.path.basename(destination)
    name = base.split(".")[0]
    format = base.split(".")[1]
    archive_from = os.path.dirname(source)
    archive_to = os.path.basename(source.strip(os.sep))
    shutil.make_archive(name, format, archive_from, archive_to)
    shutil.move("%s.%s" % (name, format), destination)


make_archive("/Users/myusername/Documents/my_folder", "/Users/myusername/Desktop/data.zip")
```

In my Documents folder i have `my_folder` with all the csv files inside it. I zip it and drop it to my desktop named as `data.zip`. When you unzip it will be `my_folder/all your csv files`

Comment: Hi, the above created a zip file with all csv's. But how do i need is my_folder/all csv files if i unzip it

Comment: If you use the above code you will notice when you unzip it will unzip a folder called `myfile/all csv files` which is what you want right?

Comment: Hi, Im still seeing the same output which when unzipped gives me csv files without folder

Comment: @viswanaththatha Try the above,